# shopify redirecting user to SDK iframe after installing the app

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I am making a shopify public app. After user installs the app, he gets redirected to https://example.com/dashboard to see and change the app settings. Everything works fine. When user later clicks the app from his shopify store, the app loads fine in shopify iframe.

Problem is, when I submitted the app for listing, they (shopify app review team) say app should open only in shopify's iframe when user installs the app.

I tried to redirect user manually to
https://shopify-shop-url/admin/apps/my-shopify-app

If I redirect to this url after installing the app, nothing shows in the iframe. This is the error in browser's console:

```
Refused to display 'https://myshop.myshopify.com/admin/apps/myappname' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
```

How solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. If anyone else if facing the same problem, add the below script to the head section of homepage:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ShopifyApp.init({
            apiKey: '{{$api_key}}',
            shopOrigin: '{{$shopUrl}}'
        }); 
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        ShopifyApp.ready(function(){
            ShopifyApp.Bar.initialize({
                 title: "Your Title"
            });

        });
    </script>
```